# Redefined variable in the other module

Tags: c++, variables, module, redefinition

Why when we redefined variable in the other modules it's ok to linking this modules together? I've written two modules `main.cpp` and `module.cpp` as the following:

```
//--main.cpp--//
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i=5;
    printf("The value of i is %d",i);
}
```

and the

```
//--module.cpp--//
int i=7;
```

Now I'm compiling and linking their with `g++` as the following:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c module.coo
g++ -o bin main.o module.o
```

And it's ok. But I'm expected that the compilation will be successful only whereas linker will throw an exception like `redefining varaible`. When I'm running `./bin` output is `The value of i is 5`.

UPD: I'm understand that if we declare `i` as global variable of module `main.cpp` that linker will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function main variable i is a local variable of the function. It is not visible and exists outside the function.

Consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 3;

int main()
{
   int i = 10

   std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
   std::cout << "::i = " << ::i << std::endl;

   i = ::i;

   std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
   std::cout << "::i = " << ::i << std::endl;

   {
        int i = 20;

        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "::i = " << ::i << std::endl;
   }

   std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
   std::cout << "::i = " << ::i << std::endl;
}
```

Local variables have no linkage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've a question about local varialbe linkage. Can you get a reference to cpp/ld-specification? It's better for me if I've read this in the spec formally :).

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Local variables don't have linkage, so you won't find any mention of it.

Comment: Ok, I've understood you.

Comment: @3.5 Program and linkage You should read section "3.5 Program and linkage" of the C++ Standard.